# Correct Way to Add byte Variables into byte Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

What I am trying to do is get input from the user and store it in a byte array. Please note, I must store var1 variable in a byte array and not a list.

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
byte var1 = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {};
byteArray[0] = var1;
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are fixed in size, you must specifiy the size of the array when you create it. In your example you told it to make an array of size 0 by putting the `{}` after the `byte[]`. Instead remove the `{}` and just put a 1 between the `[]`

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
byte var1 = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
byteArray[0] = var1;
```