# Resizing an array within a class

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an issue that's been bothering me.

I have an assignment to do which involves creating a program that does several tasks, using OOP.

The assignment is creating a shopping cart using separate classes and one of the tasks is to eliminate one item from the class.

I have it set it up like this.

Product class is:

```
class Product
{
    private string name;
    private decimal price;

    public Product(string name, decimal price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
```

Shopping cart class is:

```
class ShoppingCart
{
    private Product[] products;

    public ShoppingCart(Product[] products)
    {
        this.products = products;
    }
```

To remove the last item, I'm trying this within the ShoppingCart class.

```
public void RemoveLastProductFromCart()
{
   Array.Resize(ref products, products.Length - 1);
}
```

But it's not resizing the Product[] products and I cannot find another way to do so. I have to use arrays because we haven't gotten to lists yet.

EDIT: 
This is the test I have to check if the resizing works, and the function is called:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldRemoveLastProductInCart()
    {
        Product[] products =
        {
          new Product("Milk", 12.10m),
          new Product("Meat", 14.15m)
        };

        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart(products);
        cart.RemoveLastProductFromCart();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, products.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Arrays are fixed length by definition, aren't they? You can write a method that returns another array containing the remaining items of the previous array

Comment: Use `List<Product>` instead of array....

Comment: @Eser Read the post. He has to use an array for this assignment

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have to use arrays. I would very much like to use List, but not allowed yet.

Comment: @LaneL I read it. where is the condition of using array.....

Comment: @LaneL "I have to use arrays because we haven't gotten to lists yet." Last sentence.

Comment: Sounds like you've not "learned" List<T> yet? Is that correct?

Comment: @NathanCooper Yes. Not yet. Tutor said we're going to get there in a couple of days, but I'm not allowed to research it myself and use it. It's a step by step course.

Comment: Are you sure you've actually *called* `RemoveLastProductFromCart()`?

Comment: The .resize does indeed change the list, but it does not update the references to the array, reassign whatever reference you are using to the array after you remove the last item and see if the changes persist.

Comment: @DouglasDeTellem `ref` takes care of that.

Comment: I am guessing you are in the same class as HereToLearn, he just asked [a similar question about arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927470/correct-way-to-add-byte-variables-into-byte-arrays) and said he was not allowed to use lists either.

Comment: It's dirty, but you could just create a new array and copy the contents of the initial array into the new shorter array.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327916/redim-preserve-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your test, once you called `Array.Resize` the array the `products` variable in `ShouldRemoveLastProductInCart` and the array in `cart.products` are no longer the same array in memory.

If you made your test check `cart.products` size you would see a correct value of 1.

Comment: Damn. I really didn't see that. Thank you very much. Works now.